# Stripe Payment Links - How to make prefilled_email read-only?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I have integrated stripe payment links in my Next JS(v14.0.4) application and passing the user email in the link using **prefilled_email** parameter as described in the stripe documentation: [Customize checkout with URL parameters](https://docs.stripe.com/payment-links/customize#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters).

As per the documentation, the **prefilled_email** is **editable**. But I want this field to be read-only so that a user can not edit it. I have read through all the related stack overflow questions but all of the answers are related to `stripe.checkout.Session.create`. Is there any way to make the email field in the payment page read-only while using stripe payment links?

Payment link format that I am using:
`https://buy.stripe.com/...?prefilled_email=acd@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with `prefilled_email`.

If you really want to prevent your customer from editing the email, there are two options, both of which will require that you create a Customer object first :

- Use [Checkout Sessions](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works) instead and [pass in the Customer id](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/create). The docs mention : `If the Customer already has a valid email set, the email will be prefilled and not editable in Checkout`.
- Alternatively, use the Buy Button and pass an existing Customer : https://docs.stripe.com/payment-links/buy-button#pass-an-existing-customer

Comment: It's extra work but valuable to do this off the client, as recommended in the answer via Checkout Sessions. That way you can do all kinds of things such as prevent `prefilled_email` values from being altered.